# i can't import my third party frame work in my View controller(swift3),I am using cocoapods

Tags: frameworks, cocoapods

i can't import my third party frame work in my View controller(swift3),I am using cocoapods
Screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNErY.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should do this:

1. choose **target** -- **BuildSettings** -- find **Header Search Paths**
2. add `$(PODS_ROOT)` choose `recursive` like this [image]
3. build the project again

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Quick options:

- Check if you have launched the .xcworkspace file.
- After running the `pod install` just clean and build the code "Command+B" then write the import statement in controller class.